401 Unauthorized Error with JWT Authentication in ASP.NET Core Web API
I'm implementing JWT authentication in my ASP.NET Core Web API, and I'm encountering a "401 Unauthorized" error when calling the endpoint about the userid :
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using LostAndFoundBack.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;

namespace LostAndFoundBack.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public UserController(UserManager<User> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, SignInManager<User> signInManager, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new User
                {
                    UserName = model.Name,
                    Email = model.Email
                };

                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User");

                    return Ok(new { UserId = user.Id, UserName = user.UserName, Email = user.Email });
                }

                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }

                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);

            if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
            {
                var token = GenerateJwtToken(user);
                return Ok(new { Token = token });
            }

            return Unauthorized();
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet("get-roles")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserRoles()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            return Ok(roles);
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet("user-information")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetCurrentUser()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            return Ok(new { user.Id, user.UserName, user.Email });
        }

        [HttpGet("user-id")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserId()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            return Ok(new { user.Id });
        }

        private string GenerateJwtToken(User user)
        {
            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id)
            };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"]));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                audience: _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                signingCredentials: creds);

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }
    }
}

None of the endpoints work except the login and register

This is my program.cs:
using LostAndFoundBack.DataBase;
using LostAndFoundBack.Models;
using LostAndFoundBack.Repositories.Interfaces;
using LostAndFoundBack.Repositories;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "LostAndFoundBack API", Version = "v1" });

    // Configure Swagger to use JWT Authentication
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please enter into field the word 'Bearer' followed by a space and the JWT value",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });

    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[] {}
        }
    });
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<User>(options =>
{
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
})
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>() 
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// Configure DbContext with SQL Server and enable retry on failure
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
    sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
    {
        sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
            maxRetryCount: 5,
            maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
            errorNumbersToAdd: null);
    }));

// Configure CORS
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowFrontendApp",
        policy => policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials());
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<IItemRepository, ItemRepository>();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "LostAndFoundBack API v1");
    });
}

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("AllowFrontendApp"); // Ensure CORS is used before UseRouting/UseAuthentication/UseAuthorization
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

I want the userId to be fetched - I tried without using the authorised and also using it


I suggest you could modify the authorize attribute to specify the scheme for the authorize to check if this is working well or not .It seems it use the identity scheme by default.

The user-id endpoint doesn't have the Authorize attribute thus the User will be null and you're returning 401 in the code.
